# Tell nested resource to use specific controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have the following routes:

```
namespace :admin do
  scope 'foo', module: 'foo' do
    resources :bar
    resources :baz
  end

  scope 'lorem', module: 'lorem' do
    resources :ipsum
    resources :baz
  end
end
```

Now, I'd like the 'baz' resource to use the same controller (found at `controllers/admin/baz_controller.rb` but I'm unsure how to tell Rails I want these resources under separate namespaces but to use the same controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help.

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :baz, path: 'foo/baz', as: 'foo_baz'
  scope 'foo', module: 'foo' do
    resources :bar
  end

  resources :baz, path: 'lorem/baz', as: 'lorem_baz'
  scope 'lorem', module: 'lorem' do
    resources :ipsum
  end
end
```

Note that you need to use `as:` to be able to generate paths. But they can be something else.

Not sure if you also need to add module parameter, but you got the idea.

Comment: Yeah I was hoping there would be something nicer than this, anything more than one shared controller and it's going to be extremely ugly

Answer (score 0):

It should look something like this:

```
scope 'lorem', module: 'lorem' do
  resources :ipsum
  resources :baz, :module=>'foo', :controller=>'baz'
end
```

This depends on the module the controller is in.

See the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use) and the [Rails API](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources/resources) for more information.

Comment: When I use this, I get the following route:
`lorem/Foo::Baz#new` for example the new action. Rather than `foo/baz#new`

Comment: I updated my answer. If this doesn't work, I suppose you are out of luck.

Comment: No this still doesn't work. I have returned `admin/lorem/admin/baz` (Remember I want the baz controller under the 'admin' namespace). Thanks anyway

Comment: Sorry, I give up. I suppose the `module:` of the `scope` interferes with the `module:` of the `resources`. I don't know enough about the internals of the router to give you better advice.

Comment: Yeah I think that's exactly the issue, digging deeper myself. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do this without having messy routes is to create a new controller that inherits from the old one.

```
class Foo::BazController < Admin::BazController
end
```